# Dynamic subsetting a table and substituting it with the value from an equation

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, subset

I'm trying to substitute a value in a table with a value from an equation. I've been unable to succeed, maybe because of my limited knowledge of R Shiny

Here is my code. I can create UI from where I get:

```
input$a
input$b
input$c
```

A combination of these 3 is my key with `+` in between

```
inputkey = reactive({paste0(input$a, "+", input$b, "+", input$c)})
```

I have a CSV Table in Global.R, `eqn`. I want to use the "key" to look for a value in `eqn`:

```
dynamictable <- renderDataTable({subset(eqn, eqn$key == inputkey)
```

And look for the value in another column:
valueofx1 =  with(dynamictable , c(dynamictable $valuecolumn)

```
output$ctPred <- renderText({paste0("Prediction = ", input$Effort+valueofx1)})
```

`valueofx1` will dynamically change based on `input$a`, `input$b`, `input$c` combinations in input

Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: You should try to make a more complete [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). you shound't use `$` with subset and you need to use `()` to get reactive values.: `subset(eqn, key == inputkey())`

Comment: WOW, that helps, also I replaces subset with     eqn[eqn$Key == paste0(input$a, "+", input$b, "+", input$c), 5]